# Extend Slug beyond 5 inches

Tags: adobe-indesign, layout, document-setup

Working in InDesign CC 2015 and I wonder if there is a way to enlarge the slug area beyond the default 6". In this case, I'm using the page size to create iPhone screen layouts, the bleed to feature a mockup of the iPhone itself, and ideally the slug to feature callouts, and other directions. Unfortunately, InDesign wants me to keep those slugs on the small size, relatively speaking.

Funny thing is that I'm using 3x retina sizes so 6" would be plenty if I was working at scale.

My imagined workaround is to place the pages of this InDesign file into another, which can serve more as the "presentation", with a header, page numbers, etc. It's an extra step, but seems to be an immediate solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is have overlapping pages.
I have attached an images that shows what you need to do -

1. Document with 2 pages (NOT facing)
2. Uncheck 2 V-marks in pages panel window (right red box).
3. If your pages aren't facing you can now drag them next to each other as shown (middle red box).
4. Only then, with the move tool (left red box) move page #2 exactly on page #1 spot. You can drag or use X/Y values. They should appear as "one" now.
5. With that same tool you can change the pages size as you wish (top bar)
6. It's best to have page #1 the bigger and "bottom" one - If needed just switch between them in page panel window.
7. You're done - BTW you can set margins separately for each page - My advice is 0px to "outer" page and 20px to "inner" page (or whichever value).
8. I also added bleed for extra space if needed (remarks or whatever).
9. When you save, choose between only page #1 or only #2 or #1-2.
10. You can duplicate this 2 pages set for more similar screen usage.

Please tell me if that worked well and fit your needs.

[image: Overlapping pages]

Comment: In all my years using InDesign I never realise you can do that. Fascinating. What happens if you export a PDF? Do you get two pages?

Comment: you can export them as PDF in 2 ways:
1. Separate pages - You'll get 2 pages, #1 page with full view (because it also "has" the smaller page inside, and #2 page with inner view only.

2. Spread - You'll get full 1+2 view

Comment: I should add: In a case of 3+ pages it gets more interesting, spread options gets more handy (it flattens everything instead of multiple PDF pages), and of course you can choose only parts. A random example: choose pages 1,3,4 that will show full view, top bar, bottom bar

Comment: That's bananas; I'll have to play around with it! Good tip.

Comment: A better explanation is available on this article from InDesignSecrets.com - https://indesignsecrets.com/making-indesign-work-illustrator-multiple-artboards-large-pasteboard.php/comment-page-1

I didn't think of this as a workaround. I suppose I could create a very tall and thin page, which serves no purpose but to extend the slug size, and then build my other pages as normal. That way there would be plenty of outer space around my spread.

Still, I'd love a natural way to extend the slug size.

Comment: Asking for a natural way in this case is asking for the software to be something it's not.. 

It's better to use 1 surrounding page rather then 2-4 thin/short pages around the main work page.

Answer (score 1):

Actually dropping your Indesign file into another InDesign file is incredibly useful, and worth the extra step IMHO, especially for that particular workflow. Not only does it give you the extra artboard you need, it means you can re-use the same screen mockup in multiple places, and they are all linked to the same 'master', making changes easy. For example, let's say you have one screen that might have more than one possible user flow. You could actually place this screen into another document multiple times, allowing you to markup the different flows. Then if the design changes, you only need to edit your 'master' the once, and update the links.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion about placing within another document. We can also divide and conquer the work load, having someone work on the actual screens, and someone else work on the notations document or app flowchart.

But it's still curious to keep the slug at 6". There used to be a workaround, apparently, if you used equal slug with (click the chain icon), but it no longer works.